# Amazon SQS SIgnature error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

The string I use to sign is as follows

```
GET
sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
/XXXXXXXXXXX/Localhost
AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXNGOTNJCTGAXXXXX&Action=ReceiveMessage&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-12-26T07%3A56%3A37Z&Version=2012-11-05
```

There are '\n' characters after the first 3 lines, but not after the last, I also tried with a '\n' at the end, but the result was the same

I am them calculating

```
HMAC_SHA256(AWSKey,string)
```

I have verified the HMAC_SHA256 correctness seperately,
Finally I am calling the URL with the HMAC Base 64 encoded

```
https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/Localhost?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXNGOTNJCTGAXXXXX&Action=ReceiveMessage&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-12-26T07%3A56%3A38Z&Version=2012-11-05&Signature=06nzru1EroDLJTJDjExLbyUyQzEcct3wAp%2Bm7TOBTjb0aPWSJTIXXXXX
```

The XX..XX have been added by me.

After having gone through the documentation, few times, I am not finding the error on the same, yet I am receiving a signature did not match error.

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
</Message>
```

Comment: Yes, the queue is named "Localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be the slash between the queue name and the question mark at the beginning of the query string in the URL?  I don't think that should be there.

```
...Localhost/?AWSAccessKeyId...
            ^ remove this
```

---

Hmmm, wasn't that, eh?  Okay, here is another thought:

You say you verified the HMAC_SHA256 correctness, but are you sure this is the correct order for the arguments?  Some implementations use this convention:

```
HMAC_SHA256($data,$key)
```

You're doing the opposite.